# How To set content from a textbox in a Textfile in C#, SharePoint?

Tags: c#, string, textbox, replace

I have a text file in which I have a word like $variable. I read it all and look if the "$variable" is in it. Then I want to replace the word "$variable" to the content of a text box and afterwards write the text in the same text file back.

If I use constantly strings like

```
string var = "hello";
```

It works. But can anyone tell me how to do this with the content of a text box?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

How to write to a file
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w

and how to read from a file 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d

and to get the value from the textbox use

```
string textValue = txtMyValue.Text;
```

but then use the name you gave to your textbox

Comment: thx, but I failed on my own. I said to get content of a text box, but put nothing in it. sorry. Now it works.